# Does a database query that is ordered in memory require less server resource than including the order in the query of a Rails 3.2 app?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

We have a rails 3.2 app that has quite a few database tables and we are hitting the database quite often. I am thinking about refactoring the app to place all the queries in one area of the application controller. e.g.:

```
# DATABASE QUERIES
def get_users_in_a_group
  @users_in_a_group = User.where("group_id = ?", current_group.id)
end
```

The same query is also ordered in a variety of ways. For example @users_in_a_group is ordered by username, date_of_birth or last_login depending on the need. I am thinking of putting an area into the application that follows the DATABASE QUERIES area, e.g.

```
# ORDERED DATABASE QUERIES
def get_users_in_a_group_ordered_by_username
  get_users_in_a_group
  @users_in_a_group_ordered_by_username = @users_in_a_group.order("username")
end

def get_users_in_a_group_ordered_by_last_login
  get_users_in_a_group
  @users_in_a_group_ordered_by_last_login = @users_in_a_group.order("last_login")
end
```

From what I have read, having fewer and simpler database queries is better. I think the way my scenario above works is that the database is hit once and then the ordering is done in memory. Is this any better or worse on server resources than querying the database in a certain order e.g.:

```
@users_in_a_group_ordered_by_last_login = User.where("group_id = ?", current_group.id).order("last_login")
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is to let SQL do everything that it can, and what it can't, only then let Ruby/Rails take over.

A small note to add, as well, is to also take advantage of adding indices to your database for commonly called large quantity tables.

If you want to compare sql loads, then fire up your .irbc file and add this :

```
if ENV.include?('RAILS_ENV') && !Object.const_defined?('RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER')
  require 'logger'
  RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end
```

Finally, to answer your question, it seems that if you're calling the same group but wanting two different ways to order them, then you can save the collection as an instance variable, and then lazy load the ordering depending on selected need.

Except you'd want to change your method to this :

```
def get_users_in_a_group
  @users_in_a_group ||= User.where("group_id = ?", current_group.id)
end
```

In that, if its already been called, then we just pull what we already have and re-order it.

Comment: Thanks @Trip. +1 for great answer. Reflecting on your recommendation.